# shiny sourced function stdout to logfile to UI issue

Tags: r, logging, shiny

I made a portable shiny app with portable chrome and R. I launch rscript with vbs script in which stdout is redirected to a logfile with:

```
RScriptFile & " 1> " & logfile & " 2>&1"
```

What I want to do is to read in the log file so that the user has feedback about the calculation progress. The following reactivePoll works if the "main" shiny script is writing to the console, but it does not if a sourced function writes. **Note that both are displayed in the log file, therefore the fault is surely not in the redirection, but somewhere in my logic or in shiny.**

If I set `bool_for_testing = T` the test button works, on the other hand if I set it False not even the first "Go!" is printed on the console until the script is finished, but both are displayed real time in the logfile:

```
library(shiny)

bool_for_testing = F # note its use below!
logfile_name = "some_log_file_that_exists" # this is created by the vbs (command line) script!

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

     actionButton("btn_test", "push meh!"),

     fluidRow(

          column(12, wellPanel(style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",
                               tags$b(paste("log file is this one:", logfile_name)),
                               verbatimTextOutput("logText")
          ))
     )
)

) # end UI


server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     observe({
          if(input$btn_test > 0){

               if(bool_for_testing) {
                    # this works!
                    print("Go!")
               } else {
                    # not a letter on log here
                    print("Go!")
                    source("some_barely_interesting_function.R")
                    some_barely_interesting_function()

               }
          }
     })

     logFile <- reactivePoll(1000, session,
                             checkFunc = function() {
                                  if (file.exists(logfile_name))
                                       # should always refresh
                                       runif(1) # Sys.time() does not work either
                                  else
                                       ""
                             },
                             valueFunc = function() {
                                  readLines(logfile_name)
                             }
     )
     # # this does not work either
     # fileReaderData <- reactiveFileReader(500, session,
     #                                      logfile_name, readLines)

     output$logText <- renderText({
          text <- logFile()
          paste(text, collapse = '\n')
     })

     session$onSessionEnded(function() {

          # for portable R and chrome application
          stopApp()
          q("no")
     })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I manually open the log file it shows the progress continuously, therefore I think the GUI thread is held up until the sourced calculation is finished (if I open a new shiny window only for reading the log file, it will work well, too). Is this truly the case, and is there a workaround for this?